# JavaFX WebView simulate KeyEvent

Tags: javascript, ajax, javafx, webview, keyevent

I have a problem with firing `KeyEvent` to a `JavaFX WebView`.
I crawl a page (Facebook) and there is an `Inputfield` with Javascript/Ajax reload. When i do the Key-Type on my own Facebook load the content but if I fire the `KeyEvent` manually via `Event.fireEvent` Facebook don't load the content (But the `WebView` shows the pressed Key in the `Inputfield`).

I don't wanna use the `Robot` class because the Application should run in background without taking control over the whole userinput.

Example code:

```
public void simulateTyping(WebView wv, String text) {
    KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, 
            "a" , "a", 
            KeyCode.A, false, false, false, false);
    KeyEvent ke2 = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 
            "a" , "a", 
            KeyCode.A, false, false, false, false);
    KeyEvent ke3 = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, 
            "a" , "a", 
            KeyCode.A, false, false, false, false);
    wv.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
           System.out.println(e.getEventType()+" "+e.getText()+" "+e.getCharacter()+" "+e.getCode()+" "+e.getSource()+" "+e.getTarget());
        }
    });
    wv.fireEvent(ke);
    wv.fireEvent(ke2);
    wv.fireEvent(ke3);
}
```

So with this example code on the same facebook page I got those outputs:

```
KEY_PRESSED a   A WebView@5fbe21e7[styleClass=root web-view] WebView@5fbe21e7[styleClass=root web-view]
KEY_TYPED  a UNDEFINED WebView@5fbe21e7[styleClass=root web-view] WebView@5fbe21e7[styleClass=root web-view]
KEY_RELEASED a   A WebView@5fbe21e7[styleClass=root web-view] WebView@5fbe21e7[styleClass=root web-view]
```

And I got **exactly** the same output when I press the key myself.

Anyone here with a good clue why my own `Events` don't act in the same way like the "real" `Events` do?

**UPDATE (09.03.17):**
I investigated the problem further and it seems that my own `Events` just work purely visual. Not even the `value` attribute is set from my own fired `Events`. In Google Chrome and when I use my "Browser" the `value` attribute is set and the `Javascript/Ajax Event` is triggered.